# Efficient way of getting a subarray of an array that the indices are mapped

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix say `a`. I need to get a sub-matrix of it, which basically the indices of it are coming from a mapping on the indices of the main matrix(This map is not necessarily 1-1). I have the following code to generate the sub-matrix and here the mapping is considered to be `sum`.

```
import numpy as np
def transform(A):
    B=np.zeros(A.flatten().shape[0])
    for i in range(A.flatten().shape[0]):
        multi_idx=np.unravel_index(i,A.shape)
        B[np.sum(multi_idx)]=A[multi_idx] #the mapping applied on the indices: B[np.sum(multi_idx)]
    return B       
A=np.arange(27).reshape([3,3,3])
print A
print transform(A)
```

With output:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]
[  0.   9.  18.  21.  24.  25.  26.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`np.ogrid` can be a convenient way to make expressions based on the indices in an array. For example,

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(27).reshape([3,3,3])
B = np.zeros(A.size)
i, j, k = np.ogrid[0:3, 0:3, 0:3]
B[i+j+k] = A
print(B)
```

yields

```
[  0.   9.  18.  21.  24.  25.  26.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
```

Note that the assignment

```
B[X] = A
```

is equivalent to

```
B[X.ravel()] = A.ravel()
```

and the assignment is *done in order from left to right*. Thus, if `X` has many duplicate values, only the last value ultimately affects `B`. This has the effect of handling the non-one-to-one-ness of your map in the way you desire.

Comment: And I just want to add the sentence "For advanced assignments, there is in general no guarantee for the iteration order. This means that if an element is set more than once, it is not possible to predict the final result." to the numpy documentation (it should keep working in these well defined conditions though).

Comment: @seberg, wait a minute! :D
What do you mean? So if my map is not 1-1 its not gonna work?!

Comment: @seberg: Could you give an example where the assignment is not performed left to right?

Comment: Umm, `a = np.zeros(4); b = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]]).T; v = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2).T; a[b] = v` and compare with the transposed arrays being copied. Do all that with gh-3798 applied.

Comment: @unutbu, actually in the 1-d case it will stay left to right indefinetly, since scipy uses it, but I am thinking about promoting `x.flat[...] = ...` for that purpose.

Comment: For those wondering, [this is gh-3798](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3798).